# CakePHP and namespaces?

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces

Is there a way to put your own code into namespaces using cakephp? The following very simple controller class works fine.

```
class Customer extends \AppModel {
    var $name = 'Customer';
}
```

However, if I add

```
namespace foo\bar;
```

cakephp can't find the controller anymore. Is there some way to tell cake in which namespace it should look for controllers?

I am using cakephp 1.3 and php 5.3.

Comment: Namespaces are coming to CakePHP 3.

Comment: More than one version of PHP has namespaces.  The presence of the [tag:namespaces] tag is enough to classify this question.  No need to invoke version tags.  Especially ones that shouldn't exist any longer.  [I think you just found a bug in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179510/135887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is. CakePHP looks for classes like `PostsController` or `BlogController`, not `foo\bar\PostsController`. Maybe you can tell CakePHP in what folder to look for those classes (probably), but then it will still be looking for unnamepsaced class names.

Why would you want this in a framework that doesn't use namespaces?

Comment: Why I would want this? So that my class names don't clash with those of the framework.

Comment: I guess that's a valid point, but since the entire framework is built unnamespaced, you can just as well (better) give our classes a funny, unpronouncable, unrememberable (?) name in the framework's style. All moot. Sorry Cake won't allow it =) [Several](http://symfony.com/) [other](http://lithify.me/) [very good](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/Rudie-on-wheels) [frameworks](http://www.recessframework.org/) [that do](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Requirements) allow it though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give up  the `App::import()`  in *cakephp 1.3*. Replace it with the `include_once()`.

I got my customize vendor classes defined under a namespace works fine. Just to prevent the  collision of the custom class name with the official one.