# Import a class outside namespace

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to import a file and instantiate a class that's outside the namespace. The require_once is working, but I'm getting a class not found error when instantiating it. Is there any way around this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000996/cakephp-and-namespaces. check this link

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I did look at that thread before but couldn't find a solution. Basically it is just not looking for the class in the file I've imported, because it's restricted to the namespace it's currently in. Was wondering if there's other way around this except copy pasting the file so it can be accessible from the namespace.

Comment: When receiving errors, please always add the _complete_ error message including possible stacktraces. Also check **http://stackoverflow.com/q/30460247/1392379**

Comment: you can create it as component, helper and you can use it.

Comment: I've just sorted it, all that was needed was a backlash before, like this : $waad = new \WAAD_Authentication(); . Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply prefix the class name with a backslash, like so

```
$waad = new \WAAD_Authentication();
```

Comment: OP @george-ionita answered this himself in the comments, but I find it helpful to have it in the Answer section.